# Using powershell to count files but exclude subfolder in count and OCR extension

Tags: powershell, count

I have a directory like so: \OCRELEASE\Images$. The directory contains about 200 subfolders and each one of those subfolders also contains subfolders. So i would have:
\OCRELEASE\Images$\Image1\0-200
\OCRELEASE\Images$\Image2\0-200
\OCRELEASE\Images$\Image3\0-200

in each of the 0-200, it can contain up to 200 files. Majority of the files have no extension and labeled like 1, 2, 3, etc. I am trying to get a TOTAL count of how many files exist in \OCRELEASE\Images$\Image1 in all of its subfolders. I want to EXCLUDE any files that has a .OCR extension and I only want a count of the files with no extension (do not include the folder in the actual count, only its files). I have the following:

```
$FOLDER_ROOT = "\\mchocrelease\images$\images21"
$OUTPUT_LOCATION = "C:\imnet\OUT.txt"
Function DirX($directory)
{
    Remove-Item $OUTPUT_LOCATION

    foreach ($singleDirectory in (Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -Directory))
    {
        $count = Get-ChildItem $singleDirectory.Name -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
        $summary = $singleDirectory.FullName+"    "+$count+"    "+$singleDirectory.LastAccessTime
        Add-Content $OUTPUT_LOCATION $summary
    }
}
DirX($FOLDER_ROOT)
```

The output looks great, but it breaks down each individual subfolder and its counts. I just want a count of all the files (exlcuding OCR) in:
\OCRELEASE\Images$\Image1

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the total count of all files with no extensions that exist under `\\mchocrelease\images$\images1` then this would satisfy your request.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\mchocrelease\images$\images1 -File -Recurse | where {$_.Extension -eq ''} | measure | select -ExpandProperty count
```

Based on your sample script it seems you want more than that. Please modify your post if so.